# Android: Integer.parseInt() never throws exception

Tags: java, android, string, exception, parseint

I have some EditText in my Activity. The user has to fill them out and confirm his input. Some of the EditText are only for numbers. To make sure that there are only valid values i'm trying to cast the input to an Integer using Integer.parseInt( . . . ). The problem is no matter what the string is the NumberFormatException wont be thrown. I debuged the problem and the corosponding line is executed every time but without throwing an exception.

Here is the Code of my method:

```
private boolean formNotEmpty()
{
    boolean returnValue = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < _editText.size();i++){
        if(_editText.get(i).getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
        {
            returnValue = false;
            _toastMessage = "Es müssen alle Felder ausgefüllt werden.";
            break;
        }else if(_editText.get(i).getHint().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.rentactivity_hint_userPLZ))
               ||_editText.get(i).getHint().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.rentactivity_hint_userTelefon)))
        {
            try{
                Integer.parseInt(_editText.get(i).getText().toString().trim());
            }catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                _toastMessage += "In "+_editText.get(i).getHint().toString() +" dürfen nur Zahlen stehen. \n";
            }
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I've forgotten to set returnValue in the catch block to false. The _toastMessage gets a new string if the method returns true. This is the reason i assumed that the exception is never thrown. I'm realy sorry for the trouble i caused.

Thank you very much

Comment: Misleading title. `int` is a primitive type and therefore there is no such thing as `int.parseInt()`. Also I'm curious to know what is the `parseInt()` result for the string "asdasda" for example. Since you don't get any exception.

Comment: Are you sure that it's being called? You should expand on your question, show output!

Comment: possibly the hint is not correctly populated so there is a no hit.

Comment: why not just make the int fields only accept numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting on the code to throw you an exception, and you want to use this as a means to validate the data to accept only numbers, then this is not the right approach to this. Exception handling should'nt explicitly be used as an if-else like you suggest. A simpler, and perhaps more correct way to accomplish what you want would be :

Declare in the layout xml

```
android:inputType="number"
```

for that particular edittext you want to confine entries only to numbers.

When you do this, you only get option to type in numbers, when you try to fill that editText, as a user. After adding this in the xml, you would not need to depend on the Integer.parseInt() API to throw exception, for your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the attr of EditText:

```
android:digits="0123456789."
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits

After that user can write only numbers.